# Centering the frontpage using memoir

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, memoir, titles, double-sided

I'm using `memoir` (two-side layout). I have the problem that my front page is centered with respect to the margins, which are **not equal** in left and right side. `\begin{center}` will not solve this, since it will center the content with respect to the margins. How to fix this?

Comment: lookup `\calccentering` in the manual, or since I have an idea you might read Danish, see my LaTeX book: http://math.au.dk/videnudveksling/latex/bog/

Comment: @daleif Please, make your comment into an answer

Answer (score 4):

As suggested from [math.au.dk/videnudveksling/latex/bog/](http://math.au.dk/videnudveksling/latex/bog/):

```
\calccentering{\unitlength}                         % Calculate center length and stores in unitlength
\begin{adjustwidth*}{\unitlength}{-\unitlength}     % Adjust center
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}                 % Extra lage front page
        Front page material
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{adjustwidth*}
```